# SQLlite3 Insert values to columns based on Where condition

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, where-clause, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert values to new columns only for rows which answer a specific where condition (when a the value in Name column is equal to a given name).

This is the code I've written so far:

```
cours.execute("""INSERT INTO NewTable(Straight, Right, Left) WHERE Name = (?)
                                    VALUES (?, ?, ?) """,
                  (name, DIRECTIONS['straight'], DIRECTIONS['right'], DIRECTIONS['left']))
    conn.commit()
```

after I do the commit I get the following error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are the rows you want to match also in `NewTable`, or in a different table? Do you want to create additional new rows, or just set the columns in the rows that already exist?

Comment: What you want actually is to update the existing rows in the table and not insert new rows. Use SQLite's UPDATE

Comment: exactly the NewTable is an existing table fill with number of columns...now ive added new columns (straight right left) and i want to add the new values for each row based on the name column

Answer (score 0):

Try with an `UPDATE` statement:

```
cours.execute("""UPDATE NewTable 
                 SET Straight = ?, Right = ?, Left = ? 
                 WHERE Name = ?""", 
              (DIRECTIONS['straight'], DIRECTIONS['right'], DIRECTIONS['left'], name))
```

Comment: now its working as expected...thanks for the help!!